# $ G $ is supersoluble if and only if every normal subgroup of $ G $ with index no more than 2 satisfies the maximal permutizer condition.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Permutizer of a subgroup $ H $ of $ G $ is defined to be the subgroup generated by all cyclic subgroups of $ G $ that permute with $ H $,
i.e. $ \langle x\in G  \vert  \langle x \rangle H = H \langle x \rangle \rangle $, denoted by $ P_{G}(H) $.

A group $ G $ is said to satisfy the permutizer condition in $ G $ if $ P_{G}(H) $ strictly contains $ H $ for any subgroup $ H $ of $ G $.

A group $ G $ is said to satisfy the maximal permutizer condition if $ P_{G}(M) = G $ for any maximal subgroup $ M $
of $ G $.

$ G $ satisfies the permutizer condition if $ G $ is supersoluble.

$ G $ is soluble if $ G $ satisfies maximal permutizer condition.

Now proof of below theorem is including unknown sentence. Please help me.

Theorem: $ G $ is supersoluble if and only if every normal subgroup of $ G $ with index no more than 2 satisfies the maximal permutizer condition.

Proof: Since the supersoluble groups form a formation and supersoluble groups satisfy the (maximal)permutizer condition, we only need to prove the sufficient part. Assume the claim is false and let $ G $ be a counterexample of minimal order. Let $ N $ be a minimal normal subgroup of $ G $. Since supersoluble groups form a saturated formation and the hypotheses are, hence $ G/N $ is supersoluble.

In this proof saturated formation is unclear for me. Which theorem is used ?

Comment: Again you have written something that doesn't make sense. "and the hypotheses are ... "? I don't think it is necessary to think about saturated formations  to see that $G/N$ is supersoluble. That follows from the fact that $G$ is a counterexample of minimal order $G/N$ satisfies the hypotheses, and $|G/N| < |G|$.

Comment: I don't understand use saturated formation for this proof.

Comment: since $ G $ is counterexample of minimal order, so $ G $ isn't supersoluble. Why $ G/N $ is supersoluble?

Comment: I explained that in my previous comment. Since $|G/N| < |G|$ and $G$ is a counterexample of minimal order, $G/N$ is NOT a counterexample. So $G/N$ must be supersoluble.